# truffle migrate cause "Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value truffle migrate"

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle

When I run "truffle migrate" to deploy contract to **geth**, I got this error: **"Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value truffle migrate"**.

this is the genesis block of my private chain:

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "0xfffffffffffffff",
    "alloc":{
            "419746ad0f6de99791821388c9b85c5d85427ba4": {
            "balance": "3000000"
        },
           "3978d4dc7b2d11c9ca40cd9bd24a30dd59cf399a": {
            "balance": "4000000"
        }
    }
}
```

How can  I solve this problem ?

**NB:** it works with ganache

Comment: `3000000` is just `0.000000000003`  ETH. Try increasing your balances.

Answer (score 0):

Preallocate sufficient funds to a specific account in `genesis.json` file and use that specific account for deploying smart contract on a **private blockchain network.**